# latex was not able to process the following string (incorrect formula follows)

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to draw the following latex formula with Python:

```
  latex = '\\{[\\Delta+q]-\\iota\\}+\\pi'
```

with the following code

```
    plt.text(0.0, 0.0, latex, fontsize=14)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    plt.show()
```

but it fails with

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'\\\\{[\\\\Delta+q]-\\\\iota\\\\}+\\\\pi'
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Works pretty well for me, except that I added `$`:

```
latex = '$\\{[\\Delta+q]-\\iota\\}+\\pi$'

# or use the raw string
# latex = r'$\{[\Delta+q]-\iota\}+\pi$'
```

Output:

[image]